# Facebook like button adding padding to entire page

Tags: facebook, iframe

So we have a Facebook like button in our footer, next to a Twitter follow button. For some reason, the Facebook button is doing two different weird things:

- It's adjusting its position and "hiding" behind the Twitter button
- It's adding TONS of "padding" to the bottom of the page and to the right (whenever I delete the `iframe` from the inspector, the "padding" goes away)

It seems to do this on an inconsistent basis, but when it does, it does both at the same time. As far as I can tell, it's **only happening in Chrome**.

Has anyone seen this before or know a solution? If you want to take a look at the code, the page is at http://www.gaychristian.net/

**Update:** I've found [another site this happens on](http://thenextweb.com/conference/europe/). If you scroll down to the sign-up area, go to a different page, and then hit the back button in Chrome, the FB button moves and the document gets weird extra padding.

**Update 2:** I've found that if you place the FB button in an element that has an explicit width and height and is set to `overflow: hidden;`, the FB button will simply disappear instead of moving and causing the weird padding issue. Not a true fix, but better than it was...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap as a CSS layout/frontend library? I had a similar problem with a site I was helping out with that I didn't write myself, and I traced it back to a class attribute value for the divs that were containing the social buttons.

If so, perhaps explaining what I had will help. Two columns in the footer contained my social buttons and their class attributes looked like this:

`<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">`

which I changed to:

`<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">`

and that seemed to solve the issue.

Although I'm not a bootstrap expert so don't expect a detailed explanation of why, I suspect it's because 12+12 = 24 so there were too many columns specified in the row under the previous style according to the bootstrap grid documentation provided here:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

There may be an easier way to solve it, but that's what worked for me.

Hope this helps, happy coding!